Is it possible to specify the order in which EXCEPT operations are executed in SQL Server using Entity Framework Core?
I'd like to execute the following operation in SQL Server using Entity Framework Core (8.0.10):
A EXCEPT (B EXCEPT C) 

I'm trying to write this query:
a.Except(b.Except(c))

But EF Core always translates it like this:
A EXCEPT B EXCEPT C

Is there a way to control the order of executing EXCEPT operations?
The only solution I've found is execute
A EXCEPT B UNION A INTERSECT C

with
a.Except(b).Union(a.Intersect(c))

But I'm not sure if it's a good solution because in this way 3 operation are being executed (EXCEPT + INTERSECT + UNION) instead of 2 (EXCEPT + EXCEPT).

I don't think that's really possible. If you need that level of control you need to use a workaround as you suggested or switch to a raw SQL query

you can do b.Except(x) wait for it and then do a.Except(b) , but it will probably be slower that the a.Except(b).Union(a.Intersect(c))

Looks like translation bug. Try a.Except(b.Except(c).Distinct()).

I agree this is a bug, it should be reported to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Here's a simple repro fiddle for you to add to a Github issue https://dotnetfiddle.net/5dEjtK. Please post a link so we can upvote it. I note this but does not manifest if multiple different set operators are involved. In any case, ... INTERSECT ... INTERSECT .. is the same as ... INTERSECT (... INTERSECT ...) so it doesn't make a difference there, and the same goes for UNION

What are you actually trying to do? EF and LINQ aren't embedded SQL. They work with entities and graphs of related objects, not tables and rows. The bug may exist simply because this is an edge case, and one that's terribly inefficient in SQL as well. All those EXCEPT clauses work on all fields, not just keys. Unless the subqueries return IDs or indexed columns, the queries will always be a lot slower than using NOT IN, NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN ... Where right.Id IS NULL. And since this is an edge case, it may not get fixed

3 operation are being executed no, only one query is executed. To see the actual operations, check the execution plans of the queries. SQL Server's query optimizer already converts queries to better equivalents before generating an execution plan. BUT A EXCEPT (B EXCEPT C) is already very inefficient unless only indexed columns are involved, in which case the optimizer may convert them to the equivalent of NOT IN (... NOT IN (...)). The problem with UNION is the implied SORT and deduplication, not the number of logical operations. BUT if A is sorted, there may not be an extra sort

@PanagiotisKanavos "Unless the subqueries return IDs or indexed columns, the queries will always be a lot slower than using NOT IN, NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN ... Where right.Id IS NULL" is not true, assuming those subqueries filter by the same columns. In the vast majority of cases you'd have a key on the entity anyway, so it makes little difference as the index would be used. EXCEPT also handles nulls better. Either way, none of what you are saying is relevant to the question: if you explicitly want that EXCEPT syntax (which I have done in the past) then this is a bug.

assuming those subqueries filter by the same columns most likely they don't, because they can only use indexed columns. You don't JOIN by all columns in a table. That can't be done with LINQ's Except though. Yes, it's a bug but given it's an edge case, it won't have a high priority. The OP can wait for it to get solved, or change the query to produce the same result without Except. We still don't know what the actual query is

Try this one with two separated lines as below.

Define your sets as below.
var setA = dbContext.SetA; // Represents your A set
var setB = dbContext.SetB; // Represents your B set
var setC = dbContext.SetC; // Represents your C set

Firstly get B except C result.
var bExceptC = setB.Except(setC);

Finally, get A except bExceptC result.
var result = setA.Except(bExceptC);



Doesn't work, you get the same thing https://dotnetfiddle.net/xReUE5

This code is identical to the original. Extracting the various expressions into variables doesn't execute them.  setB.Except(setC) doesn't retrieve anything, it creates a new LINQ query. The final query in this answer is result.  EF will generate SQL from the entire query when it gets executed, either because ToList is called or because the final IQueryable gets iterated
